# Integrating data-provider to application without using sql or nosql servers

Tags: java, sql, database, deployment, setup-deployment

I'm creating a simple CMS software which doesn't have much data to be stored. I'm currently using mysql as my data provider and have  a java application in the presentation layer. This CMS will be a standalone which means datacollection and processing will be done in a single computer.

I created a installer to install in my clients computers. But I need to setup mysql then the database as well. And my clients  doesn't have sufficient IT knowledge to setup the databases themselves. So for each client I have to attend and install mysql server.

What I need is a way to integrate data-provider to the application without using mysql or any other sql or nosql server. So my clients can install it themselves using simple guided steps in installation wizards.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of embedded db, like JavaDB (ex. Derby). Support of this database is added to JRE. So all your client need is installed JRE. And you get full relational database without any installation and other stuff setup.

Comment: Thankyou very much word I was exactly looking for is embedded db, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Yes, I use JavaDB for one of project that need local database. Work greate. You can edit schema of this db in NetBeans editor.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [hsqldb](http://hsqldb.org/) or [sqlite db](http://www.sqlite.org/). These dbs can be bundled with the application in memory or can use a simple file as db. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I found a good example here 
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javadb/

thanks every one for help